# custom ldap schema to hold expiry dates and statuses

Tags: ldap, schema

I need to store account creation and expiry dates in our existing ldap.
None of the standard existing schemas seem to quite fit the bill, not even ppolicy or samba.

The answer I've come across so far is: "use a custom schema".

Fine, but I can't seem to find an existing custom schema to hold account creation and expiry dates. Shurely someone has already had to store this kind of info in their ldap and has therefore used (maybe even created) such a schema, no? If I can't find one, does this mean I will really have to write my own custom schema and all? Seems like I'd be inventing the wheel again frankly, I'm sure I've missed something but I just can't find an existing schema for my needs (or at least one from which I could take existing attributes and objectClasses and plonk them in my schema...).

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While there may be no standard schema universally used, many LDAP servers come with existing attributes like `creationTimestamp` and some kind of Account Expiration Time.